# How is postal tracking info retrieved?

Tags: api, post, tracking

I noticed there are several shipment tracking sites. Does anyone know how tracking parcels is done from different post offices? Post offices don't have public `API`s (at least not all). Do post offices perhaps use means that don't use the Internet?

Comment: Could you provide some more information about what you are trying to achieve? "Does anyone knows tracking parcels is done" is a nice question :), although it misses what you want to accomplish or learn.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.trackingmore.com - these guys seem to have integrations with most postal operators. You can hook into their single API and gain access ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going through your post, I find two questions embedded in it:

1. How do websites track couriers across multiple sites and delivery partners, and
2. How are parcels from different post offices tracked?

Let me answer the second question first:

> 2) How are parcels from different post offices tracked?

Every postal network worth its salt will be using some kind of technological solution to track packages - capturing information like where they originated from, which intermediate hop they are currently at, and where will they be delivered. You can get this information only for packages which have a tracking number, so a registered post or equivalent is trackable, but a simple stamped post may not be trackable.

For example, [India Post allows you to track by consignment number](https://www.indiapost.gov.in/VAS/Pages/TrackConsignment.aspx).
A tracking number is essentially linked to a bar code, which is physically implanted on the parcel (think barcode stickers). A group of  parcels at any stage could be collectively referred to as a shipment (probably within a container of their own), each shipment having a barcode. As such, every time shipments are moving between hops, the tracking information is getting updated based on either the shipment barcode or the parcel barcode. At every stage up to actual delivery, the successive hops are thus identified.

Just like banks and ATMs are connected to centralized infrastructure and so you don't get to withdraw all your money from different bank branches many times over; Every post office doesn't have its own tracking solution, they are all connected to centralized servers when they are part of the same postal network.

Sometimes these postal network may expose their APIs, while at other times, independent hackers may write wrappers around their UI features that were exposed for retail consumers to track packages. For example, here is a [github project which helps get the tracking information from India Post, in API format](https://github.com/captn3m0/indiapost-tracker).

Now, coming back to the first question:

> 1) How do websites track couriers across multiple sites and delivery partners

Many delivery partners may provide their package track API's, while others may do it via a custom form on their website. For example, [Delhivery in India have their  APIs](https://docs.aftership.com/delhivery-tracking-api) to track packages.

Thus, every generic courier tracking site has to either integrate APIs from a courier agency, or has to put `Iframe`s where it is loading the delivery partner's tracking mechanism.

A simple google search for `track courier` could give you a list of many such sites. Selecting one at random, [TrackCourier.in](http://www.trackcourier.in/), it is easy to see that they have written one PHP page per courier partner they have, embedding iframe for the courier agency within their site.

---

OP says in comments,

> I don't think 17track or trackitonline.ru use iframes... Then these
>   tracking sites only need to partner with a singel post office to get
>   access to the entire tracking system.

Sadly, that is not the case. Going through the multiple sites mentioned by OP, the sites clearly mention that they integrate newer channels on their own, and this usually happens via API.

> 1. So trackitonline [mentions on its about page](http://en.trackitonline.ru/?service=about): Track It generally aggregate information provided by official deliverer companies *using their public or internal syatems and databases*, except some transport companies, which have no such systems.
> 2. And [17track has this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWl4Y.png) on its [website](https://www.17track.net/en): Started from dozens of postal carriers and *integrated 100's of cross border* logistics provider.

(I've emphasised in Italics the relevant information)

Essentially, all such sites either have preferential access to the systems of postal companies, or have developed means to integrate their functionality via iframes and other UI hacks.

Comment: I don't think 17track or trackitonline.ru use iframes. My guess is that all post offices have some kind of internal network, and any one of them can check any tracking number, not just their own. Then these tracking sites only need to partner with a singel post office to get access to the entire tracking system.

Comment: @Alex Nopes, there is no centralized system.. Check edits to my answer.. All such sites mention that they integrate multiple partners.. Logistics can be a very complicated business, and different companies adopt different technologies based on their business needs leaving big system compatibility gaps in the industry

Comment: Not even for national post offices (regular mail)? Their tracking numbers are standardized, like RxxxxxxxxxXY

Comment: @alex USPS will have one system across all its post offices, similarly, India Post will have one system across all it's post offices. However, both will have different systems, since the solutions would be developed by different software vendors. It seems you are confusing a post office with a postal network - a USPS post office is only a physical extension of the USPS postal network. So, the USPS post office would be connected to the central system of USPS in a client server manner. For 3rd party to integrate with USPS, it has to integrate with USPS central systems, and not with post office.

Comment: @Alex If that helped, don't forget to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Postoffices don’t host API’s for their individual locations. Instead, **each delivery network hosts its own API**. For a postoffice to connect with any delivery network API it suffices to have a proper barcode scanner, a computer/handheld/phone and an internet connection. This is basically the same process as when you sign the handheld device when the mail deliverer is at your door; these devices are wireless connected to the internet.

Most postoffices are connected to a whole bunch of services. Among these services are a fair amount of post delivery networks such as FedEx; as most post delivery networks do, FedEx offers an API, designed to serve a range of ‘consumers’: manufacturers, online shops (websites, apps), mail deliverers, customer applications, and postoffices. At the moment a package is scanned at any point during its journey, the status of the package is changed via the API.

Depending of the country you live in, there might be a centralized ‘postoffices API’ which routes information of each scanned package automatically to the proper ‘post delivery network API.’

See for more information [PostNL API](https://developer.postnl.nl) and [Fedex API](https://www.programmableweb.com/api/fedex).

Comment: Please read [What types of questions should I avoid answering?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260087/add-what-types-of-questions-should-i-avoid-answering-to-the-help-center) before attempting to answer more questions.